# Pub/Sub Implementation in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-integration, google-cloud-pubsub

Currently in our project we already implemented firebase messaging service(FCM).We already have service account created for this. Now we need to implement a pub/sub with different google and service account.
When I try to implement this its taking default credentials.

How can we configure different service account credentials for FCM and pub/sub?

Kindly let me know how can we fix this.

[default credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV8nr.png)

[Dependencies added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7VDT.png)

[Error I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eGeF.png)

Answer (score 1):

To explicitly provide credentials for Spring Cloud GCP Pub/Sub, use the `spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.credentials.location` or `spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.credentials.encoded-key` property.

Documentation available [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/3.2.0/reference/html/index.html#spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-api-configuration).

The error you have is unrelated to GCP authentication, though -- the issue is that two different starters are defining a Jwt parsing bean. If you don't need to extract identity from Firebase, then it can be turned off with `spring.cloud.gcp.security.firebase.enabled=false`. If you do need it, and com.magilhub is under your control, follow the Spring Boot suggestion and use `@Qualifier` to get the specific one you need.